# How do I read a String from a class, Java?

Tags: java, string

When I try to compile this, I get tons of error, as I have "illegal start of type", and expected semicolons, parentheses, etc. I have got no idea how to read what's behind each door. ><

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Paradox {
public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("You have got three doors, there is a price inside each of them. Pick a door: A, B, or C");
    Door A = new Door();
    Door B = new Door();
    Door C = new Door();

    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(3);
    System.out.println(i);

    if(i==0) {
        A.goatorcar="Car";
        B.goatorcar="Goat";
        C.goatorcar="Goat";
    }
    else if (i==1){
        A.goatorcar="Goat";
        B.goatorcar="Car";
        C.goatorcar="Goat";
    }
    else {
        A.goatorcar="Goat";
        B.goatorcar="Goat";
        C.goatorcar="Car";
    }
}

System.out.println(A.goatorcar);
System.out.println(B.goatorcar);
System.out.println(C.goatorcar);

}

class Door {
String goatorcar;
}
```

Comment: There are several posts on compilation errors, learn how to understand compilation errors before posting here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra closing brace `}`:

```
} <<<<

System.out.println(A.goatorcar);
System.out.println(B.goatorcar);
System.out.println(C.goatorcar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the System.out.println() statements.  In Java, you cant just "do" things.  Statements like that (function calls) must be inside of a function, in this case your main function.